# How to read a sql expression

Tags: mysql

I am very new to sql and trying to understand a simple aggregate expression.

```
 sum(if(i.action = 'clean_delete', 1, 0)) as uninstalls,
```

What exactly the above expression mean or will do. I am having a hint it means if `action` = `clean_delete` assign it as 1 , else 0 .. but why `sum` ?

Sorry for being dumb at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sums up how many times the condition is true.
In other words how many `action`s are `clean_delete`.

```
if(i.action = 'clean_delete', 1, 0)
```

returns `1` if the condition is true and `0` otherwise. In MySQL you could even reduce that to

```
sum(i.action = 'clean_delete') as uninstalls
```

Comment: what's with the `i` ?

Comment: `i` is the alias name (or short name) for the table. At some point of your query you do something like `from table_name i` or `join table_name i`

Comment: Note: The two expressions are not equivalent - They handle NULLs differently.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: No, the result is the same

Comment: `(1 = NULL)` is not the same as `IF(1 = NULL, 1, 0)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: Yes, but the result in the `sum()`  does not care.

Comment: @juergend SUM() returns NULL, if all values are NULL. But it returns 0, if all values are 0. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8Av37h3aTDzqLd2B75pfp/0

Answer (score 0):

If the action has the text 'clean_delete', 1 is returned; else 0.
So, this is summing up the cases where action is 'clean_delete' and using the alias uninstalls.